# Como fazer um tutorial de primeiro acesso ao site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5, css3

Gostaria de criar um **Tutorial de Primeiro Acesso ao meu Site**, aqueles que mostram o que significa cada campo do site, preciso de uma dica de como fazer ou se existe algum Framework para este tipo de interação com o usuário, efetuei algumas pesquisas e não encontrei nada, provavelmente porque não sei o nome correto deste tipo de interação. Alguém teria alguma dica?

Comment: http://github.hubspot.com/shepherd/docs/welcome/

Answer (score 5):

Acredito que a melhor ferramenta seja:

http://bootstraptour.com/ segue a documentação, exemplo:

```
var tour = new Tour({
  steps: [
  {
    element: "#my-element",
    title: "Title of my step",
    content: "Content of my step"
  },
  {
    element: "#my-other-element",
    title: "Title of my step",
    content: "Content of my step"
  }
]});
```

Super facil, basta conhecimento em javascript.

Answer (score 4):

Quando se esta utilizando Bootstrap, o bootstraptour é a melhor opção como o @Guerra propos, mas caso o contrário eu recomendo o [hopscotch](http://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch). Com ele você define os `steps` com json, é bem simples:

```
{
      id: "welcome_tour",
      steps: [
        {
          target: "header",
          placement: "bottom",
          title: "This is the navigation menu",
          content: "Use the links here to get around on our site!"
        },
        {
          target: "profile-pic",
          placement: "right",
          title: "Your profile picture",
          content: "Upload a profile picture here."
        },
        {
          target: "inbox",
          placement: "bottom",
          title: "Your inbox",
          content: "Messages from other users will appear here."
        }
      ]
    }
```